# Python Database API, written in what?

Tags: python

Just a quick quick question cause i cant find the answer anywhere. What programming language is the Python Database API v2.0 written in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's just an API it's actually [written in plain English](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). It depends on the driver on what language it's *implemented* - there are pure Python DB clients and there are ones written in C.

Comment: Alright, thanks for claring it up!